# Enable Bluetooth auto-connect in Windows 11

Tags: audio, bluetooth, windows-11

So far I was using my Bluetooth headphones with Windows 10 and whenever I turned them on, they're connecting to my PC automatically. Now, I have switched to Windows 11 and each time I turn my wireless headphones on I must go to Bluetooth settings and connect them manually, because they always appears a "Paired" only.

Is there anything to do to have them auto-connected like it was in Windows 11?

[Setting them as default audio device](https://superuser.com/a/232853/156554) brings absolutely no effect.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet? I've the same issue where auto-connect was working in W10 but not in W11. I have to manually reconnect everytime I turn them on

Comment: @xperator Yes, I have found, but you are not going to like it. I have changed my headphones (the same manufacturer, older model) to the one that auto-connects without any problems on both W10 and W11. I have also contacted manufacturers support, but all that they could tell me is that there is some bug or missing in those new headphones' firmware that prevents them from auto-connecting under W11, but I have to wait (supposedly forever) because they don't have any firmware update so far for this model.

Comment: That's a bummer. Not long ago I read in an article that there is an upcoming W11 build (number `22563`) with better Bluetooth connection support. Although from the looks of it it  just seems to be a quick settings shortcut where you can connect to the device quicker. We'll have to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth works fine in Windows 11 (2 such machines) and has done since Windows 11 was introduced.  Auto reconnect works every time.

Try updating the Bluetooth driver, either by downloading from the Manufacturer Site; or by Device Manager, locate Driver and update from there.

You might also consider updating BIOS on your machine in the event a new Bluetooth driver interacts with BIOS.

Finally it may be your particular headphones and its interaction with Windows 11. The only cure I know for that is probably newer ones.

Comment: As said in my answer, the very same headphones works just fine (auto-connect) in Windows 10, so I hope that your last option is wrong. I'll check your other solutions and report here. Thank you for all your advices.

Comment: You are using WIN11 so there may be a compatibility issue with WIN11 so yes, let us hope drivers fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry, nope. Bluetooth and chipset drivers updated to the newest version, same with BIOS. Computer restarted many times, headphones re-paired at least once, all for nothing. Must be something with Windows 11, because getting back to my old PC with Windows 10 and headphones again magically re-connect automatically after each power-on. I have filled up manufacturer support for this headphones, but I don't expect anything to be fixed this way. Probably another (out of many) weird feature of Windows 11 which makes me closer to decision of going back to ol'good Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

The following method worked for me and solved my problem:

> Set the Bluetooth service startup type to Automatic. Sign in to your computer as an administrator user and then follow the steps given below to change the startup type of Bluetooth Support Service.
>
> 1. Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.
> 2. Type services.msc and scroll down to `Bluetooth Support Service` in the list.
> 3. Right click on it and select Properties.
> 4. Set up Start up type to `Automatic` from the dropdown list.

Source: [Bluetooth headphones are paired but don't autoconnect anymore](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/bluetooth-headphones-are-paired-but-dont/a34fc951-e292-4fbd-b1c7-7b00db5518f1).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Method 2: Run the Hardware and Devices troubleshooter.

1. Type troubleshooting in the search bar.
2. Select Troubleshooting.
3. Select View all on the top left corner.
4. Click on Hardware and Devices.
5. Follow the on-screen instructions to run the troubleshooter.
6. Check if issue persists.

Source: [Bluetooth headphones are paired but don't autoconnect anymore](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/bluetooth-headphones-are-paired-but-dont/a34fc951-e292-4fbd-b1c7-7b00db5518f1)